# Excel SUM of Equation Results

Tags: excel-formula

O.K. I have a problem using Excel SUM, when the components being summed are the results of equations.

I have read various blogs and taken on board the advice of encapsulating said equations using VALUE.

However, I still have problems with two columns where all the cells are of type "Currency" and have equations encapsulated with VALUE.

An example of one of the cells being SUMmed is:

```
=VALUE((C13*E13)-G13) {all such cells are in column F}
```

where C is a simple value of type Number
      E is an equation of type Currency encapsulated with VALUE and
      G is an equation of type Currency encapsulated with VALUE

the SUM statement for eight such above mentioned cells is:

```
=VALUE(SUM(F6:F13))
```

However, the said sum is £0.03 too high!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a "problem" caused by formatting. What you see in cell, may not actually be the value inside the cell.

Try using a General formatting for all the summed cells, to see what is going on. Then act accordingly.

[image]

The proper way of dealing with this problem, is to explicitly [ROUND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUND-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c) numbers entering the SUM.